# PHP execute jpg file

Tags: php, mod-fcgid

I'm currently using apache_worker + fcgi + php .(ubuntu 10.04) 
Recently, I found these kind of errors appear in php error log.

> [08-Aug-2012 12:31:28] PHP Warning:  Unexpected character in input: 
>   '' (ASCII=7) state=1 in /path/to/image/file.jpg on line 68

I did some google on the topic but most search result occur with php file when php encounter syntax error.

And, I found some server have these errors too. 
example : http://www.greepit.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/error_log

> [02-Aug-2011 03:18:06] PHP Warning:  Unexpected character in input: 
>   '' (ASCII=23) state=1 in
>   /home3/greepitc/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/jquery-plugin-html5-canvas-to-animate-images.jpg
>   on line 197

Have you guys have any ideas to this problem? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There must be an error in the configuration so that PHP is responsible for the images.

Comment: The config has been checked all other image file are ok. except some of them.